# Passing Records to subprogram parameter C++

Tags: c++, parameters, struct

How do I pass a struct to a subprogram parameter?
When I call my checkBelow function it gives me an error -'CheckBellow' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'playerInfo' to 'char'
I've passed arrays of records before, but this is my first time trying to pass a single one.

```
  struct playerInfo
{
    char playerName[81];
    char playerID;
};

void CheckBellow ( char board[][10], char playerID, int dropChoice );
int PlayerDrop();
void DisplayBoard ( char board[][10] );

int main()
{
    playerInfo playerOne, playerTwo;
    char board[9][10];
    int trueWidth = 7; 
    int trueLength = 6; 
    int dropChoice;

    cout << "Let's Play Connect 4" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Player One please enter your name: ";
    cin  >> playerOne.playerName;
    playerOne.playerID = 'X';
    cout << "Player Two please enter your name: ";
    cin  >> playerTwo.playerName;
    playerTwo.playerID = 'O';

    DisplayBoard( board );
    dropChoice = PlayerDrop();
    CheckBellow( board, playerTwo, dropChoice );
    DisplayBoard( board );


return 0;
}

void CheckBellow ( char board[][10], playerInfo activePlayer, int dropChoice )
{
    int width = 7;
    int length = 6;

    do
    {
        if ( length == 0 )
        {
            cout << "That row is full, please enter a new row";
            dropChoice = PlayerDrop();
            length = 6;
        }
        if ( board[length][dropChoice] != 'X' && board[length][dropChoice] != 'O' )
            board[length][dropChoice] = activePlayer.playerID;
        else
            --length;
    }while ( board[length][dropChoice] != 'X' && board[length][dropChoice] != 'O' );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void CheckBellow ( char board[][10], playerInfo activePlayer, int dropChoice )`

doesn't match with declaration

`void CheckBellow ( char board[][10], char playerID, int dropChoice );`

Fix the declaration i.e. 2nd parameter `char` -> `playerInfo`